# Парсинг XML на python

Tags: python, xml

Вопрос следующий нужен парсинг XML файла, необходимо вытащить поочередно определенные теги, например тег `name`

Код следующий, не работающий

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('файл.xml').getroot()

for type_tag in root.findall('shop/offers/offer'):
    value = type_tag.get('name')
    print(value)
```

Файл тут https://sotiknadom.ru/snprice.xml

Очень прошу о помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с BeautifulSoup

```py
# pip install bs4 lxml (если не установлены)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('snprice.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as xml:
        soup = Soup(xml.read(), 'lxml')

    names = [offer.find('name').text for offer in soup.find_all('offer')]
    print(names, sep='\n')
```

А это рабочий вариант Вашей реализации:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = ET.parse('snprice.xml')

for type_tag in xml_file.findall('shop/offers/offer'):
    value = type_tag.find('name').text
    print(value)
```

Ну или можно немного сократить код:

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

print(
    *(
        type_tag.text for type_tag in parse('snprice.xml').findall('shop/offers/offer/name')
    ),
    sep='\n'
)
```

> Не рекомендуется, если не уверены в исходных данных и нужны какие либо проверки в ходе выполнения

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Всем, кто столкнется с такой структурой XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<title>SotikNadom</title>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html">https://sotiknadom.ru/</link>
<updated>2020-08-01T06:03:43Z</updated>
<entry >
**<g:**title>Монитор Acer K242HLbd (черный)</g:title>
**<g:**link>https://sotiknadom.ru/monitory/monitor-acer-k242hlbd-chernyj</g:link>
**<g:**price>8800.00 RUB</g:price>
**<g:**id>51</g:id>
**<g:**availability>in stock</g:availability>
**<g:**condition>new</g:condition>
```

Делать так:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = ET.parse('sngoogle2.xml')

for type_tag in xml_file.findall**('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry')**:
    value = type_tag.find**('{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}price')**.text
    print(value)
```

Документация: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces